# Why does the SHA512 hash of my SD card change while Overlay File System is enabled?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-buster, filesystem

I enabled “Overlay File System” to make file system read-only.

I was surprised to see that the SHA512 hash (computed using `sudo openssl dgst -sha512 /dev/rdisk2`) of my SD card changes each time I reboot the Pi.

Why?

Comment: How do you determine the SHA512 of the card (exact command pls)? Update the question with this information

Comment: The SD card is more than just the root filesystem.  If you want a hash of the root fs, you have to target the appropriate partition (the 2nd one by default w/ raspbian).  It's not clear what `rdisk2` refers to, I'm guessing you did this in a Mac, not the pi itself.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @goldilocks. On macOS, `rdisk2` targets the whole disk. I assumed that given the file system was read-only, nothing would change on the SD card and its hash would be identical between boots. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, it makes sense -- I'm just pointing it out.  You could at narrow down what changes this way.  There are often un-intuitive gotcha's w/ tech etc.  Eg., something could have been toggled by the Mac; if the first partition had the "dirty bit" set, I'm guess it would check and repair (which might just mean unsetting the dirty bit).  Which of course raises the question how certain fs metadata is handled in this scenario.

Comment: @goldilocks I was able to narrow down the problem... the issue appears to be with the boot partition changing. Ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the timestamps on the files there to see if anything was explicitly changed.